# Private s3 file visible to public - django

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I want to upload a file to s3 using a FileField in django but i want the file to be private. I tried creating a new field like -

```
class S3PrivateFileField(models.FileField):

def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, upload_to='', storage=None, **kwargs):
    super(S3PrivateFileField, self).__init__(verbose_name=verbose_name,
            name=name, upload_to=upload_to, storage=storage, **kwargs)
    self.storage.default_acl = 'private'
```

When i check my s3 console, it shows that the file is private. But i am still able to download the file from admin, which is fine. I want to keep the file private from the rest of the world. Any suggestions? Thanks

My bucket policy.

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "---------------------"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Why do you think this isn't working as expected?

Comment: If i knew that, I wouldn't have posted the question here.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question.  I'm not asking about the cause of the behavior -- I'm asking about the cause of your belief: *What makes you believe the file is not currently private?*  What does "download the file from admin" mean?

Comment: I can download the file from django admin. I can use the link of the file to download it from anywhere (incognito window/phone/some other laptop).

Comment: "The link of the file" ... does the link in question have `Signature=` or `X-Amz-Signature=` in it?

Comment: No. http:// ------/abc.csv

Comment: Now we are getting somewhere. :)  It sounds like your bucket policy may be allowing anonymous downloads.  The "private" ACL doesn't override that.  Show the bucket policy?  If you have your public files uploaded as "public-read" then you don't also need a bucket policy allowing anonymous downloads, but I've seen people configure both, usually unnecrssarily.

Comment: If by bucket policy, you mean permissions, then only i have the permissions.

Comment: I have added the bucket policy above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In S3 (and IAM) policy/permissions evaluation, an action...

- ...is implicitly denied by default, and will be denied
- ...unless it is explicitly allowed, in which case it is allowed
- ...unless it is also explicitly denied, in which case it will always be denied.

Bearing these rules in mind, the `private` canned ACL isn't an explicit "deny."  The private canned ACL is only, in fact, an explicit "allow" for the owner.

Your bucket policy grants anonymous users the ability to perform `s3:GetObject` on all the objects in your bucket.  This is one way to make everything in a bucket readable, but it is only useful if you really want *all* objects to be readable.

Another way to make objects readable is to set their ACLs, individually, to the canned ACL `public-read`.  This accomplishes the same purpose as the policy statement, and if the objects are all set this way, then such a policy statement should be unnecessary, because it is redundant.

To store private content and public content on the same bucket means you can't use a blanket policy like this, because -- as you have observed -- it makes everything readable.

You'll either need to set the ACL to `public-read` on public objects to make them readable at the object level and remove this policy statement, so that other objects aren't implicitly public -- or create a more complex bucket policy to grant public access to only certain prefixes.  Instead of the resource `arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*`, if your objects are so organised you might be able to use (for example) `arn:aws:s3:::bucket/asset/*` which would only match objects with the prefix `asset/`, making only a subset of the bucket's objects publicly accessible.

Comment: Thanks man. This help a lot. I am new to s3 and django. I should have researched a little more before asking though.